# Converting from XML to JSON using org.json: how to preserve number format?

Tags: java, json, xml, org.json

I am converting simple XML to JSON using `org.json` lib:

```
import org.json.JSONObject;
import org.json.XML;

public class TestJson {
    public static void test_number() {
        String xml = "<BALANCE>32032033.10</BALANCE>";
        JSONObject jsonObj = XML.toJSONObject(xml);
        String json_str = jsonObj.toString(4);
        System.out.println(String.format("%s\n----\n%s", xml, json_str));
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try {
            test_number();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

My results:

```
<BALANCE>32032033.10</BALANCE>
----
{"BALANCE": 3.20320331E7}
```

As you see the format of number changed from normal, to scientific. How can I preserve number format? I would like to see JSON as:

```
{"BALANCE": 32032033.10}
```

or preferable as string:

```
{"BALANCE": "32032033.10"}
```

I use `org.json` from `json-20190722.jar`

Comment: 3.20320331E7 and 32032033.1 if treated as numbers are exactly equivalent. Neither your code or any client code should care.

Comment: Of course they are the same as numbers, but not for grep or other text utilities.

Comment: Then yeah, strings are the way to go. Numbers should be treated as such.

Comment: @Michał Niklas, which version of org.json lib you are using?

Comment: @Michał Niklas, your existing code will work if it is possible for you to upgrade your org.json lib version to something higher than 20090211(it seems you are using an older version of this i.e. may be 2009 release version as shown above) release.

Comment: I use `json-20190722.jar` downloaded from maven repository

Comment: @Michał Niklas, could you try using this version once <dependency>
    <groupId>org.json</groupId>
    <artifactId>json</artifactId>
    <version>20140107</version>
</dependency>

Even 20180813 will also work

Comment: With `json-20140107.jar` it works as expected.

Comment: Underscore-java library can convert xml to json. U.xmlToJson(xml) method.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hope the below code will help to resolve the issue.  Please use `XML.toJSONObject(xml,true)` instead of XML.toJSONObject(xml);

```
import org.json.JSONObject;
import org.json.XML;

public class TestJson {
    public static void test_number() {
        String xml = "<BALANCE>32032033.10</BALANCE>";
        JSONObject jsonObj = XML.toJSONObject(xml,true);
        System.out.println(String.format("%s\n----\n%s", xml, jsonObj.toString()));
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try {
            test_number();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Output:

```
<BALANCE>32032033.10</BALANCE>
----
{"BALANCE":"32032033.10"}
```

Answer (score 1):

Here you could use either

```
 <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.json/json -->
 <dependency>
      <groupId>org.json</groupId>
      <artifactId>json</artifactId>
      <version>20140107</version>
 </dependency>
```

Then your existing code will work without any change.

Otherwise you want to go with the latest version i.e. `json-20190722.jar`, then you need to pass true as an extra parameter in your `toJSONObject(String string, boolean keepStrings)` method as suggested by @vigneshwaran m.

```
where @param keepStrings If true, then values will not be coerced into boolean
     *  or numeric values and will instead be left as strings
```

This is from json-20190722.jar javadoc, check here https://github.com/stleary/JSON-java/blob/master/XML.java

Answer (score 0):

You have a `String` that you get by parsing the JSON using this line:

```
String json_str = jsonObj.toString(4);
```

You can preserve or reset the format by creating a `BigDecimal` from that `String` and applying the number formatting using `setScale(...)` like this:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String json_str = "3.20320331E7";
    BigDecimal bigDecimal = new BigDecimal(json_str);
    System.out.println(bigDecimal.setScale(2, BigDecimal.ROUND_HALF_UP));
}
```

The output of that example `main` is this:

```
32032033.10
```

Comment: I would prefer text only conversion from XML: tread every data as simple String.

Comment: @MichałNiklas OK, you can do so... Find the index of `E` in the `String`, get the number after that `E` and shift the comma/dot accordingly... Might work.